# Intent Filter to capture all sharing Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I set my activity to be able to respond to any type of Sharing Intent.

I have tried:-

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

However this does not work, I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html but it is not clear how to be that open?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The `data` filter can only be wildcard:ed on the *subtype*, ("`text/plain`" has the subtype "`plain`" for instance) - so you'd need to add "`application/*`", "`audio/*`", "`image/*`" etc. etc. to your filters.

Comment: So @Jens do you meant that I have to add each and every data filter individually? If so is there somewhere I can get a list of them from?

Comment: [RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) lists all the "well-defined" types. Then, there's of course a lot of *people* who just likes to take huge steaming shits on top of standards and make up their own `type`s without using the `x-token` format.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is how it is done:-

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation for the code  you've provided.

Comment: The comment about `*/*` not working must be dated, because the source code for [Send to SD card](https://bitbucket.org/gelin/send-to-sd) contains the exact intent-filter above in it's AndroidManifest.xml. And the program works like intended (on Android 6.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<action android:name="com.yourapppackage.LAUNCH" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="application/*" />
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
<data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
<data android:mimeType="video/*" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
<data android:mimeType="message/*" />
```

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried this?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that but my application is never listed when I share something.