# Android Manifest, how to receive shared URL, files and contacts?

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, share

I see around it's a recurring question regarding ACTION_SEND and which filters to use, but I can promise I searched for this.

The app development is going fine and for my testings until now I've been using images and videos:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but now I would like to expand the app to accept ANY file (no matter what type it is), contacts (there's an option to share contact on the Contacts app) and URL (usually sent from the Browser).

for the URL I saw people using the Text before `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />` but I sounds to me like a very generic approach for a very specific char sequence.

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: "I sounds to me like a very generic approach for a very specific char sequence" -- then don't accept URLs. There is no MIME type for a URL, because URLs are not usually standalone files.

Comment: I understand mimeTypes are all for files. But I wonder if Google didn't implement a `<data android:type="URL" />` or `<data android:type="CONTACT" />` for example. Which is not mimeTypes but types that can be used for Sharing around the system.

As for, any file type, maybe if I put `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` will it do? I'll try when I get home and update the thread.

Comment: "As for, any file type, maybe if I put <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> will it do?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: I've finally had time to get back at this project and test it. Nope. I tried "*", "*/*" and "/" and no mimeType specified. A couple of those give me a launch error due to malformed Manifest, "*/*" works but I still can only share from the gallera (not from file managers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161863/906362

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Why it needs the category.DEFAULT I don't know, but without it, it will only work for the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

To get any mimetype:

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```